# How use dig method several for children object

Tags: ruby

I have an hash

```
{:result=>
  {:"1"=>
    [{:"1"=>1,
      :"2"=>"4698192612070913717",
      :"5"=>
      {:"1"=>{:"1"=>"1.0.0"},
        :"2"=>
        {:"1"=>1,
          :"2"=>"1525341956127",
          :"3"=>1000000000,
          :"4"=>0,
          :"5"=>{:"1"=>1000000000}},
        :"3"=>["17"],
        :"6"=>"4704522736971289334",
        :"8"=>["4618851880555471022"],
        :"9"=>[1]},
      :"6"=>{:"3"=>{:"2"=>false}, :"4"=>{:"1"=>false}},
      :"7"=>{:"1"=>1},
      :"8"=>"production"},
    {:"1"=>4,
      :"2"=>"4700283765268993541",
      :"6"=>{:"2"=>{:"1"=>200}, :"3"=>{:"2"=>false}, :"4"=>{:"1"=>false}},
      :"8"=>"beta"},
    {:"1"=>5,
      :"2"=>"4699074054925986704",
      :"6"=>{:"2"=>{:"1"=>100}, :"3"=>{:"2"=>false}, :"4"=>{:"1"=>false}},
      :"8"=>"alpha"},
    {:"1"=>10,
      :"2"=>"4697702456121346981",
      :"6"=>{:"2"=>{:"1"=>50}, :"3"=>{:"2"=>false}, :"4"=>{:"1"=>false}},
      :"8"=>"internal"}],
  :"3"=>{:"1"=>true, :"2"=>{:"1"=>{:"1"=>false}, :"2"=>{:"1"=>false}}},
  :"4"=>false},
:xsrf=>"AMtNNDFJl06mR54j2zxFjYIYfGQR22sUKA:1528830206790"}
```

I am looking for simple way to return a value or nil

I have tried this

```
result[:'result'][:'1'][1].dig(:'5').dig(:'1').dig(:'1')
```

but it's not working

What can I do to avoid this

```
if result[:'result'][:'1'][1].dig(:'5')
puts result[:'result'][:'1'][1][:'5'][:'1'][:'1']
end
```

Comment: `result[:result][:'1']` at index `1` does not have a key of `:'5'` otherwise "not working" is not really an explanation. Formatting helps alot and ruby `Array`s start at index 0. I think you are looking for `result[:result].dig(:'1',0,:'5',:'1',:'1') #=> '1.0.0'`

Comment: In future please pare down your examples to their essential structure. Here I would think your hash need have more than a dozen lines. Also, for hashes, keep keys and values short. For example, shorten `"AMtNNDFJl06mR54j2zxFjYIYfGQR22sUKA:1528830206790"` to, say, "AMn". Also, it's helpful to assign a variable to all input objects (here, say, `h = {:result=>...}`. That way, readers can  refer to the those variables (here `h`) in comments and answers without having to define them.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind dig is that you can go several levels deep into a hash at the same time and return nil if the key doesn't exist at any level during the 'digging'. So `result[:'result'][:'1'][1].dig(:'5', :'1', :'1')` will do what you are looking for and clean up your code as well. In fact, you could make it a little safer if you wanted by doing `result.dig(:result, :'1', 1, :'5', :'1', :'1')`

Answer (score 1):

`dig` is not a single method, but a family of four methods, all of which made their debut in Ruby v2.3: [Array#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-dig), [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig), [Struct#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Struct.html#method-i-dig) and [OpenStruct#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-dig).

For example,

```
h = { a: [1, { c: 2, d: 3 }], b: 2 }
h.dig(:a, 1, :d)
  #=> 3
```

employs `Hash#dig` because `dig`'s receiver is a hash. Moreover, one might expect that when, in an intermediate calculation, `dig` has unearthed `[1, { c: 2, d: 3 }]` it will pass the shovel to `Array#dig` for further excavation.

Suppose

```
h = { a: [1, 2] }
```

Then

```
h.dig(:a, 1)        #=> 2
h.dig(:a).dig(1)    #=> 2
```

Does that mean the two are equivalent? Try this:

```
h.dig('cat', 1)     #=> nil
h.dig('cat').dig(1) #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `dig' for nil:NilClass
```

The exception is due to the fact that `h.dig('cat') #=> nil` and [NilClass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/NilClass.html) has no instance method `dig`, so `nil.dig(1)` raises the exception. No, the two expressions are not equivalent.

If the value of the variable `result` is the OPs hash, we have (as pointed out by @Isaiah) the following.

```
result.dig(:result, :'1', 0, :"5", :"1", :"1")
  #=> "1.0.0"
result.dig(:result, :'1', 0, :cat, :"1", :"1")
  #=> nil
```

Note that `dig` will still raise an exception if the wrong data type is used:

```
[1, 2].dig(:a)
  #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

To support versions of Ruby prior to 2.3 (where `dig` is not available) we can write the following, using [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

```
arr = [:result, :'1', 0, :"5", :"1", :"1"]
arr.reduce(result) { |memo, obj| memo && memo[obj] }
  #=> "1.0.0"

arr = [:result, :'1', 0, :cat, :"1", :"1"]
arr.reduce(result) { |memo, obj| memo && memo[obj] }
  #=> nil
```